# Update database according to value

Tags: php, mysqli

I have some code that is supposed to update the database according to some values. It's a game, in my game I have "attack" and "defense". I also have ranks (called "playerrank" in database). I want the rank to change in accordance to how much "attack" and "defense" a player has. Sounds simple doesn't it? Well it's not :( for me anyway..

Here's what I mean

Attack between 1 and 1000, rank is 1
Attack between 1001 and 2000, rank is 2
etc

The problem is that the rank stays at 1 no matter how much attack/defense I have and I get no error message!

Here's the relevant code

```
if ($attack AND $defense >1 && $attack AND $defense < 1000){
$update_rank = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 1 WHERE stats.id=$id4");

}elseif ($attack AND $defense >1001 && $attack AND $defense < 2000){
$update_rank2 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 2 WHERE stats.id=$id4");

}elseif ($attack AND $defense >2001 && $attack AND $defense < 3000){
$update_rank6 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 3 WHERE stats.id=$id4");

}elseif ($attack AND $defense >3001 && $attack AND $defense < 4000){
$update_rank5 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 4 WHERE stats.id=$id4");

}elseif ($attack AND $defense >4001 && $attack AND $defense < 5000){
$update_rank4 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 5 WHERE stats.id=$id4");

}elseif ($attack AND $defense >5001 && $attack AND $defense < 6000){
$update_rank3 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 6 WHERE stats.id=$id4");

}
```

Here's the full code

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
include("header.php");
$username = $_SESSION['userlogin'];
$getattack = "SELECT stats.id, stats.attack, users.id, users.username FROM stats, users WHERE users.username = '$username' AND stats.id = users.id";
$getdefense = "SELECT stats.id, stats.defense, users.id, users.username FROM stats, users WHERE     users.username = '$username' AND stats.id = users.id";
$gotattack = mysqli_query($con,$getattack);
$gotdefense = mysqli_query($con,$getdefense);
$attack = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gotattack);
$defense = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gotdefense);

$rankstatsget = "SELECT stats.id, stats.playerrank, users.id, users.username FROM stats, users WHERE         users.username = '$username' AND stats.id = users.id";
$rankstatsgot = mysqli_query($con,$rankstatsget);

$id_get = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT stats.id,users.id, users.username FROM stats, users WHERE     users.username = '$username' AND stats.id = users.id");
$gotid = mysqli_fetch_array($id_get);
$id4 = $gotid["id"]; 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rankstatsgot, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo "Current Rank: {$row['playerrank']}  <br> ".

     "--------------------------------<br>";
} 

if ($attack AND $defense >1 && $attack AND $defense < 1000){
$update_rank = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 1 WHERE stats.id=$id4");

}elseif ($attack AND $defense >1001 && $attack AND $defense < 2000){
$update_rank2 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 2 WHERE stats.id=$id4");

}elseif ($attack AND $defense >2001 && $attack AND $defense < 3000){
$update_rank6 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 3 WHERE stats.id=$id4");

}elseif ($attack AND $defense >3001 && $attack AND $defense < 4000){
$update_rank5 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 4 WHERE stats.id=$id4");

}elseif ($attack AND $defense >4001 && $attack AND $defense < 5000){
$update_rank4 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 5 WHERE stats.id=$id4");

}elseif ($attack AND $defense >5001 && $attack AND $defense < 6000){
$update_rank3 = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 6 WHERE stats.id=$id4");

}

Echo "Your rank is up to date!";

?>
```

Comment: Why the mix and match of `AND` and `&&` in `if ($attack AND $defense >1 && $attack AND $defense < 1000){` and what is that logic supposed to actually check? because `AND` and `&&` are Boolean comparison operators.... do you mean `if ($attack + $defense >1 && $attack + $defense < 1000){`?

Comment: @MarkBaker it's supposed to see if attack and defense are greater than 1 but also lower than 1000, the line afterwards updates the rank to 1. Tried changing to your version and didn't work :(

Comment: You mean to see if attack is greater than 1 and defense is greater than 1?.... the word AND has a very specific meaning in computing terms, and you're using it very ambiguously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOUND THE PROBLEM MYSELF

I needed to put

```
if ($attack['attack'] + $defense['defense'] >1 && $attack['attack'] + $defense['defense'] < 1000){
$update_rank = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 1 WHERE stats.id=$id4");
```

Instead of

```
if ($attack AND $defense >1 && $attack AND $defense < 1000){
$update_rank = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 1 WHERE stats.id=$id4");
```

Because the query wasn't returning the right type of answer for the IF statement

Noob mistake :/

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the greater then en smaller then value per variable

```
if ($attack >1 AND $defense >1 && $attack < 1000 AND $defense < 1000){
$update_rank = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 1 WHERE stats.id=$id4");
```

etc...

or

```
if (($attack >1 OR $defense >1) && ($attack < 1000 OR $defense < 1000)){
$update_rank = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE stats SET stats.playerrank = 1 WHERE stats.id=$id4");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing `AND` and `&&` with no brackets. Those two operators have different [binding precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php), so your if() tests undoubtedly executing differently than what you think they are.

e.g.

```
$attack AND $defense >1 && $attack AND $defense < 1000
```

would be parsed as

```
$attack && (($defense > 1) && $attack) && ($defense < 1000)
```

Comment: I see, didn't know that! I'll make the changes and see if it works

Comment: if (($attack > 1 AND $defense > 1) && ($attack < 1000 AND $defense < 1000)){ - is correct? didn't work :(

Comment: well, what are the values you're feeding in there?

Comment: Attack is 1040, defense is 1001

Comment: Ah, I tried to echo the attack and defense but I'm getting a string conversion error, may be that I'll sort it asap